# Multi-page form

Tags: php, html

I'm on internship at web programming company. I must do a project of 3 page form.

Form from first page:

```
<form action="step2.php" id="form" method="post">
            Собствено име               <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $fnameErr; ?></span>           <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
            Бащино име                  <input type="text" name="mname" /><br>
            Фамилно име                 <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $lnameErr; ?></span>           <input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
            Потребителско име (login)   <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $loginErr; ?></span>          <input type="text" name="login" /><br>
            Електронна поща             <span class="alert"> * <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>           <input type="text" name="email" /><br>
            Телефон                     <input type="text" name="phone" /><br><br>
            <span class="alert"> * Полетата са задължителни </span><br><br><br><br>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Стъпка 2" name="submit">
```

Validation from first page:

```
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $loginErr = $emailErr = "";
        $fname = $mname = $lname = $login = $email = $phone= "";


        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if(empty($_POST["fname"])) {
                $fnameErr = "Собствено име е задължително";
            }  
            if(empty($_POST["lname"])) {
                $lnameErr = "Фамилно име е задължително";
            }  
            if(empty($_POST["login"])) {
                $loginErr = "Потребителско име е задължително";
            } 
            if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $emailErr = "Електронна поща е задължителна";
            } 


        }
```

What I need to do is, when I submit the form to check for empty "input", if there are none to submit the data and store it into session and redirect to step2.php. If there are errors to show refresh the page showing the errorr messages.

P.S. Sry for my bad english, my second language ;-;

EDIT: A friend of mine told me that I need to do the verification with request method, but im not sure how to do it.. since im new to PHP

Comment: and what have you tried so far? were are u stuck?

Comment: Have you started with any introductory PHP tutorials?  Storing values in session and redirecting users to another page are fairly simple concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   // validation code
   // if validation passes, store and redirect
}
```

Put your form beneath this in your code, with the action set to the page itself (step1.php). When the page is posted, it will go through your validation code. If that's successful you can redirect.

Comment: what should be the "if validation passes" 
`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 if(empty($_POST["fname"])) {
 $fnameErr = "Собствено име е задължително";
 }  
 if(empty($_POST["lname"])) {
 $lnameErr = "Фамилно име е задължително";
 }  
 if(empty($_POST["login"])) {
 $loginErr = "Потребителско име е задължително";
 } 
 if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $emailErr = "Електронна поща е задължителна";
 } 
// what should i write in here ?

 }`

Comment: First assign your session variables in the ELSE statements of your validation IFs. Then you need to redirect, perhaps with `header`. I can't write the whole thing for you. There are lots of tutorials and books on PHP, I suggest walking before you can run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($_POST["fname"]=='') {
            $fnameErr = "Собствено име е задължително";
        }  
        if($_POST["lname"] =='') {
            $lnameErr = "Фамилно име е задължително";
        }  
        if($_POST["login"]=='') {
            $loginErr = "Потребителско име е задължително";
        } 
        if($_POST["email"]=='') {
            $emailErr = "Електронна поща е задължителна";
        } 
    }
```